# Lucene.net 4.8: Search by facet field

Tags: lucene.net, faceted-search

I am trying to write a filter in lucene.net which matches all blog posts who have at least one tag from a set of tags.

I'm trying the following but this always returns 0 results:

```
           var bq = new BooleanQuery();

            var termsQuery = new BooleanQuery();
            foreach (var tag in tags)
            {
                termsQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("TagSlugs", tag)), Occur.SHOULD);
            }
            bq.Add(termsQuery, Occur.MUST);

            var hits = searcher.Search(bq, page * pageSize);
```

What am I doing wrong?

My document looks like this:

```
        var doc = new Document
        {
            new StoredField("Id", blogPost.Id),
            new Int32Field("ModuleId", blogPost.ModuleId, Field.Store.YES),
            new TextField("Title", blogPost.Title, Field.Store.YES),
            new StringField("Slug", blogPost.Slug, Field.Store.YES),
            new StoredField("ImagePath", blogPost.ImagePath),
            new TextField("Intro", blogPost.Intro, Field.Store.YES),
            new TextField("Html", blogPost.Title, Field.Store.YES),
            new Int64Field("PublishDate", blogPost.PublishDate.Ticks, Field.Store.YES),
            new FacetField("PublishDateTag", blogPost.PublishDate.Year.ToString(), blogPost.PublishDate.Month.ToString(), blogPost.PublishDate.Year.ToString())
        };

        foreach (var tag in blogPost.TagObjects)
        {
            doc.Add(new FacetField("Tags", tag.Name));
            doc.Add(new FacetField("TagSlugs", tag.Slug));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Facet in this specific case, you can use a simple String field and filter by that.

But if you are looking to use Facets, try reading this demo https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/demo/org/apache/lucene/demo/facet/SimpleFacetsExample.html

It's in Java, but readable if you are C# developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the facet field, you can simply add a TextField with the same name as the FacetField.

```cs
foreach (var tag in blogPost.TagObjects)
{
    doc.Add(new FacetField("Tags", tag.Name));
    doc.Add(new FacetField("TagSlugs", tag.Slug));
    doc.Add(new TextField("TagSlugs", tag.Slug, Field.Store.NO)); // <-----
}
```